# HTML files not added to compiled folder when run 'Grunt' - Yeoman scaffold

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I used Yeoman to scaffold my site. I want to use jade templates which so far is half working, my jade files go to the tmp as html files folder and livereload is displaying this fine, but when I run grunt to build my site the html files from folder .tmp do not get placed into my public_html folder. All other folders/assets as expected are going to public_html.

Here is my folder structure apologies for the bad illustration:

- site name
  ---- .sass cache
  ---- .tmp
- app
  ---- bower_components
  ---- images
  ---- jade
  ---- scripts
  ---- styles
- public_html
  ---- bower_components
  ---- scripts
  ---- styles

  ```
  // Generated on 2013-11-11 using generator-webapp 0.4.3
  'use strict';

  // # Globbing
  // for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
  // 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
  // use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
  // 'test/spec/**/*.js'

  module.exports = function (grunt) {
      // show elapsed time at the end
      require('time-grunt')(grunt);
      // load all grunt tasks
      require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
      // configurable paths
      site_name: {
          app: 'app',
          public_html: 'public_html'
      },
      watch: {
          compass: {
              files: ['<%= site_name.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
              tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
          },
          styles: {
              files: ['<%= site_name.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
              tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
          },
          jade: {
              files: ['<%= site_name.app %>/jade/{,*/}*.jade'],
              tasks: ['jade']
          },
          livereload: {
              options: {
                  livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
              },
              files: [
                  '.tmp/{,*/}*.html',
                  '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                  '{.tmp,<%= site_name.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                  '<%= site_name.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
              ]
          }
      },
      connect: {
          options: {
              port: 9000,
              livereload: 35729,
              // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
              hostname: 'localhost'
          },
          livereload: {
              options: {
                  open: true,
                  base: [
                      '.tmp',
                      '<%= site_name.app %>'
                  ]
              }
          },
          test: {
              options: {
                  base: [
                      '.tmp',
                      'test',
                      '<%= site_name.app %>'
                  ]
              }
          },
          public_html: {
              options: {
                  open: true,
                  base: '<%= site_name.public_html %>'
              }
          }
      },
      clean: {
          public_html: {
              files: [{
                  dot: true,
                  src: [
                      '.tmp',
                      '<%= site_name.public_html %>/*',
                      '!<%= site_name.public_html %>/.git*'
                  ]
              }]
          },
          server: '.tmp'
      },
      jshint: {
          options: {
              jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
          },
          all: [
              'Gruntfile.js',
              '<%= site_name.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
              '!<%= site_name.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
              'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
          ]
      },
      mocha: {
          all: {
              options: {
                  run: true,
                  urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
              }
          }
      },
      compass: {
          options: {
              sassDir: '<%= site_name.app %>/styles',
              cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
              generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
              imagesDir: '<%= site_name.app %>/images',
              javascriptsDir: '<%= site_name.app %>/scripts',
              fontsDir: '<%= site_name.app %>/styles/fonts',
              importPath: '<%= site_name.app %>/bower_components',
              httpImagesPath: '/images',
              httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
              httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
              relativeAssets: false,
              assetCacheBuster: false
          },
          public_html: {
              options: {
                  generatedImagesDir: '<%= site_name.public_html %>/images/generated'
              }
          },
          server: {
              options: {
                  debugInfo: true
              }
          }
      },
      autoprefixer: {
          options: {
              browsers: ['last 1 version']
          },
          public_html: {
              files: [{
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                  src: '{,*/}*.css',
                  dest: '.tmp/styles/'
              }]
          }
      },
      // not used since Uglify task does concat,
      // but still available if needed
      /*concat: {
          public_html: {}
      },*/
      'bower-install': {
          app: {
              html: '<%= site_name.app %>/index.html',
              ignorePath: '<%= site_name.app %>/'
          }
      },
      // not enabled since usemin task does concat and uglify
      // check index.html to edit your build targets
      // enable this task if you prefer defining your build targets here
      /*uglify: {
          public_html: {}
      },*/
      rev: {
          public_html: {
              files: {
                  src: [
                      '<%= site_name.public_html %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                      '<%= site_name.public_html %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                      '<%= site_name.public_html %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                      '<%= site_name.public_html %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                  ]
              }
          }
      },
      jade: {
          public_html: {
              options: {
                  pretty: true
              },
              files: [{
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: '<%= site_name.app %>/jade',
                  dest: '.tmp',
                  src: '{,*/}*.jade',
                  ext: '.html'
              }]
          }
      },
      useminPrepare: {
          options: {
              dest: '<%= site_name.public_html %>'
          },
          html: '<%= site_name.app %>/index.html'
      },
      usemin: {
          options: {
              dirs: ['<%= site_name.public_html %>']
          },
          html: ['<%= site_name.public_html %>/{,*/}*.html'],
          css: ['<%= site_name.public_html %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
      },
      imagemin: {
          public_html: {
              files: [{
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: '<%= site_name.app %>/images',
                  src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                  dest: '<%= site_name.public_html %>/images'
              }]
          }
      },
      svgmin: {
          public_html: {
              files: [{
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: '<%= site_name.app %>/images',
                  src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                  dest: '<%= site_name.public_html %>/images'
              }]
          }
      },
      cssmin: {
          // This task is pre-configured if you do not wish to use Usemin
          // blocks for your CSS. By default, the Usemin block from your
          // `index.html` will take care of minification, e.g.
          //
          //     <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
          //
          // public_html: {
          //     files: {
          //         '<%= site_name.public_html %>/styles/main.css': [
          //             '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          //             '<%= site_name.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
          //         ]
          //     }
          // }
      },
      htmlmin: {
          public_html: {
              options: {
                  /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                  // https://github.com/murata/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                  //collapseWhitespace: true,
                  collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                  removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeOptionalTags: true*/
              },
              files: [{
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: '.tmp',
                  src: '*.html',
                  dest: '<%= site_name.public_html %>'
              }]
          }
      },
      // Put files not handled in other tasks here
      copy: {
          public_html: {
              files: [{
                  expand: true,
                  dot: true,
                  cwd: '<%= site_name.app %>',
                  dest: '<%= site_name.public_html %>',
                  src: [
                      '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                      '.htaccess',
                      'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}',
                      'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                      'bower_components/sass-bootstrap/fonts/*.*'
                  ]
              }]
          },
          styles: {
              expand: true,
              dot: true,
              cwd: '<%= site_name.app %>/styles',
              dest: '.tmp/styles/',
              src: '{,*/}*.css'
          }
      },
      modernizr: {
          devFile: '<%= site_name.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
          outputFile: '<%= site_name.public_html %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
          files: [
              '<%= site_name.public_html %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
              '<%= site_name.public_html %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
              '!<%= site_name.public_html %>/scripts/vendor/*'
          ],
          uglify: true
      },
      concurrent: {
          server: [
              'compass',
              'copy:styles'
          ],
          test: [
              'copy:styles'
          ],
          public_html: [
              'compass',
              'copy:styles',
              'imagemin',
              'svgmin',
              'htmlmin'
          ]
      }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
      if (target === 'public_html') {
          return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:public_html:keepalive']);
      }

      grunt.task.run([
          'clean:server',
          'jade',
          'concurrent:server',
          'autoprefixer',
          'connect:livereload',
          'watch'
      ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:test',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:test',
      'mocha'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
      'clean:public_html',
      'useminPrepare',
      'concurrent:public_html',
      'jade',
      'autoprefixer',
      'concat',
      'cssmin',
      'uglify',
      'modernizr',
      'copy:public_html',
      'rev',
      'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
      /*'jshint',*/
      'test',
      'build'
  ]);
  ```

  };

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run `grunt htmlmin`?

I'm thinking that the `htmlmin` task isn't running, for some reason. Perhaps it's not running because of the `concurrent` task, as in this other SO answer:

- [Grunt build - Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task Killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391364/grunt-build-running-concurrentdist-concurrent-task-killed?rq=1)

Notice that in your gruntfile, the `htmlmin` declaration copies html files from `.tmp` into `<%= site_name.public_html %>`.

You might also try `grunt build --force` to make grunt continue through any errors that may be preventing grunt from eventually running `htmlmin`.

Answer (score 0):

Think your issue is in your htmlmin task

```
htmlmin: {
    public_html: {
        options: {
            /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
            // https://github.com/murata/grunt-usemin/issues/44
            //collapseWhitespace: true,
            collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
            removeAttributeQuotes: true,
            removeRedundantAttributes: true,
            useShortDoctype: true,
            removeEmptyAttributes: true,
            removeOptionalTags: true*/
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp',
            src: '*.html',
            dest: '<%= site_name.public_html %>'
        }]
    }
},
```

needs / at end of '<%= site_name.public_html %>' eg

```
dest: '<%= site_name.public_html %>/'
```

maybe ?